# How to make a plot in R shiny - error when I create the plot in my app

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am trying to plot a graph in my app. I do not mind what kind of graph I create or what package I use. Ideally, I would like to create a plot that reflects the results in my table. I am using a numeric variable to plot the graph that has values above 1000000. I don't know if that makes a difference.

I used a tutorial to create the code from https://deanattali.com/blog/building-shiny-apps-tutorial/#4-load-the-dataset but when I changed it to suit my data, the app will not plot a graph.

```
    ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Euoprean Emissions"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      radioButtons("typeInput", "Gas",
                   choices = c("Carbon dioxide", "Methane", "Nitrous oxide"),
                   selected = "Carbon dioxide"),
      radioButtons("sectorInput", "Sector",
                   choices = c("Total", "Agriculture, forestry and fishing", "Mining and quarrying",
                               "Manufacturing", "Electricity, gas, steam and air con", "Water supply, Sewerage",
                               "Construction", "Motor Wholesale", "Transportation and storage",
                               "Accommodation and food", "Info and communication", "Financial and insurance",
                               "Real estate", "scientific and technical", "Administrative ",
                               "defence", "Education", "Healt","Arts", "Other"
                               ),
                   selected = "Total"),

      uiOutput("countryOutput")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("emmisionsplot"),
      br(), br(),
      tableOutput("results")
        )))

        server <- function(input, output) {
          output$countryOutput <- renderUI({
            selectInput("countryInput", "Country",
              sort(unique(emissions$Country)),
                selected = "Ireland")
    }) 




    filtered <- reactive({
      if (is.null(input$countryInput)) {
        return(NULL)
      }        
      emissions %>%
        filter(Type == input$typeInput,
              Sector == input$sectorInput,
               Country == input$countryInput
        )
    })

    output$coolplot <- renderPlot({
      if (is.null(filtered())) {
        return()
     }
        ggplot(filtered(), aes(Emissions)) +
       geom_histogram()
    })

    output$results <- renderTable({
      filtered()
    })
```

I want to create a graph in my app that reflects the data in the rendered table but it keeps giving me an error.

This is the part that is causing the error:

```
    ggplot(filtered(), aes(Emissions)) +
      geom_histogram()
```

The error is "StatBin requires a continuous x variable: the x variable is discrete. Perhaps you want stat="count"?"

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thnaks

Comment: What does you `UI` code look like? Do you have example data for `filtered()`

Comment: And can you provide more info about what kind of error you're getting? A real error message (and if so, what does it say?) Or just no plot?

Comment: Does `shiny` really matter here, or can you reproduce the error on the console? What exactly is the error? (BTW: the shiny-idiomatic way is to use `req(filtered())` instead of `if (is.null(filtered())) { return(); }`. You may want to use `req` in `output$results` as well (and similarly to your first `reactive`).

Comment: @phalteman  The error is "StatBin requires a continuous x variable: the x variable is discrete. Perhaps you want stat="count"?"

Comment: @RyanMorton I have uploaded the full code. Thanks for taking a look

Comment: Have you tried using `stat="count"` in your call to `geom_histogram()`? It sounds like @r2evans might be right - the error might have not much to do with shiny, and more to do with what data you're feeding to your `ggplot` call.

Comment: @phalteman I added in 'count'. The graph shows up but there are no values on the graph. Do you know any graph I could use and what commands I need to fill in?

Comment: It's impossible to give you anything other than guesses without seeing your data, as @RyanMorton suggested in the first comment. It sounds like a histogram isn't the right plot for you, but I can't tell you what a better alternative is without seeing your data.